# Changing marker properties (google maps) when all marker-objects have the same name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javascript-objects

I have a google map on my website that is populated with markers through PHP. What I don't understand is how I can identify each marker individually since all marker objects have the same name.

This code is taken from the google developers page ( https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 )

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon,
      shadow: icon.shadow
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }
});
```

For instance. If I want to make one of the markers invisible I usually use `marker.setVisible(false)`. However, in this case all markers have the same name ("marker").

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of all markers by keeping them in a list, for instance:

```
var markers = [];
for (/* .. */) {
    /* .. */
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
console.log(markers); // prints a list of all markers
```

You can then do:

```
markers[2].setVisible(false);
```

to make the marker at position 2 invisible.

Comment: That works! Thanks. I tried to do this but instead of "var markers = []" I used "markers = new Array()". How come my approach did not work?

Comment: Maybe because you didn't use `var` and you put it in a strange spot? `new Array()` is similar to `[]` but the latter is preferred.